# Bad data format for React Highchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

First hello,

To explain my issue : I got some issue with Highchart, I want to select by default All in the zoom selector (the option is selected: 5) but I'm not able to select any one of the selector range.

What I troubleshoot is that my data are in the wrong format, I have :

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {x: 1599264000000, y: 39}
1: {x: 1599350400000, y: 39}
2: {x: 1599436800000, y: 39}
3: {x: 1599523200000, y: 59}
4: {x: 1599609600000, y: 46}
5: {x: 1599696000000, y: 50}
6: {x: 1599782400000, y: 53}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

=> I get this by doing :

```
const qos = datas?.map((data) => ({
            x: (data.date && data.date.utc(true).valueOf()) || 0,
            y: (data.qos !== undefined && (100 - data.qos)) || undefined
        })).sort();
console.log(qos);
```

But I need to have it on this format :

```
[{x: 1599264000000, y: 39},
{x: 1599350400000, y: 39},
{x: 1599436800000, y: 39},
{x: 1599523200000, y: 59},
{x: 1599609600000, y: 46},
{x: 1599696000000, y: 50},
{x: 1599782400000, y: 53}];
```

-> this is a JSON array, right? What's the difference between both? What should I do to have the same format

Edit:

```
console.log(typeof (qos), JSON.stringify(qos, null, 2));
```

give me:

```
object [
  {
    "x": 1599264000000,
    "y": 39
  },
  {
    "x": 1599350400000,
    "y": 39
  },
  {
    "x": 1599436800000,
    "y": 39
  },
  {
    "x": 1599523200000,
    "y": 59
  },
  {
    "x": 1599609600000,
    "y": 46
  },
  {
    "x": 1599696000000,
    "y": 50
  },
  {
    "x": 1599782400000,
    "y": 53
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: The first one looks like what you see in the console inspecting a variable.  The 'needed' format looks like the same thing, just as JSON.  What happens if you just do 'qos = []` with `[]` being the array of data?  I'm thinking there's a different issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer !! I'm not sure to understand what you want me to do. 
Yes, I'm very disapointted, for me, it's the same. I try to use the qos in my code : it's not working, but if I'm creating a const with the second array, then, it's working... that's very strange for me. Is it because of the metadata?

Comment: Can you edit one of highcharts's demo fiddles to use your data and show the problem?  Those two things look equivalent to me, I'm not understanding the difference.  Can ytou try `console.log(typeof(qos), JSON.stringify(qos, null, 2))` for the one that isn't working and add that to your question?

Comment: I updated the post. I don't know how to create a demo with my data.

Comment: Please reproduce your issue on the online editor. Here you can find the basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6eutbk0f/ - try to reproduce how the `qos` variable is getting.